# Read blob types from cassandra in spark with spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I need to read cassandra `blob` types in spark with [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and compare two datasetes based on blob field.

As example following code shows my mean:

```
// Cassandra Table 
CREATE TABLE keyspace.test (
  id bigint,
  info blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

case class Test(
  id:   Long,
  info: java.nio.ByteBuffer
)
session.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map(
    "table"     -> tableName,
    "keyspace"  -> keySpaceName,
    "cluster"   -> clusterName
  )).load().map(i => Test(i.getLong(0), i.get???(1)))
```

I need method instead of `i.get???(1)` to read blob as ByteBuffer. I've tried `row.getAs[Array[Byte]](i)` but it doesn't satisfied my need because can't compare two objects.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `ByteBuffer` is not solution, because Spark doesn't provide default encoder for it and I must develop my Encoder for it first to read and use it. Anyway `ByteBuffer` implements `equals` method around content.

But for simple usage I read `blob` as `Array[Byte]` and convert it to `Seq[Byte]` which has default encoder.

```
case class Test(
  id:   Long,
  info: Seq[Byte]
)
session.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map(
    "table"     -> tableName,
    "keyspace"  -> keySpaceName,
    "cluster"   -> clusterName
  )).load().map(i => Test(i.getLong(0), (i.getAs[Array[Byte]](1)).toSeq ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is getBytes and it returns a ByteBuffer

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.